# Which Python version used in Django project? 2 or 3?

Tags: python, django, version

When I open someone's Django project, I need a time for understanding which Python version is used here. I try to find print or print() methods, but some Django projects contain both print methods.
How I can at once know, which version of Python is used in the Django project?

Comment: `print ()` works with the print statement in Python 2, but `print` does not work in Python 3. If you see `print` then the project is written for Python 2, or it's a bug.

Comment: It's not always possible to say, projects may support both python 2 and 3 with the same code. If only one is supported, a code linter configured for a specific python version may give some obvious errors when checking against an unsupported version. Other than that, just run the code to see if it works, or look for telltale signs (such as `print` without brackets).

Comment: Yeah, but before running the code you should install virtualenv (for the any Python version) and all dependencies.

Comment: That's right, you'll have to install the dependencies for whatever Python version you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of the syntax that isn't backwards compatible with python 2. Use it to determine their version.

[What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Comment: It does nothing. You wiil see default system Python version.